# Why angular2 one-way binding between components works wrong with objects?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-formbuilder

I have parent and child components. 
I want to send form's values from parent to child component. 
Child component can do everything with this data, but all changes are local and should not be returned back to parent component.

**When i send a simple variable** to child comp – everything works fine and changes doesn't returned back to parent. 
**But when i send form's values** – all changes returns back to parent component...

#### Live

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvqyjr

#### Parent Component JS

```
export class AppComponent  {
constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder){};

simpleVariable = 'Value';
form: FormGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    id: 1,
    name: 'Name'
});
```

#### Parent Component HTML

```
<hello [simpleVariable]="simpleVariable" [form]="form.value"></hello>
```

#### Child Component JS

```
export class HelloComponent  {
  @Input() simpleVariable;
  @Input() form;
}
```

#### Child Component HTML

```
<input [(ngModel)]="simpleVariable">
<input [(ngModel)]="form.name">
```

#### Question

So how can i send an object to child component and modify it without returning data to parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple. The reason for this behavior is that the `form.value` is an object. Meaning that you're sharing a reference object with parent and child. Meaning that any change to this object will result in a change in both parent and child.

In order to make changes in child that won't affect your parent, create a deep copy of your object using `Object.assign` function and use it in your child component.

```
export class HelloComponent implements OnInit {
  _from: {};
  @Input() simpleVariable;
  @Input() form;

  ngOnInit() {
    this._form = {};
    Object.assign(this._from, this.form);
  }
}
```

[Forked and edited example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzuniy)

Comment: Thanks! So how can i send an object to child component and modify it without returning data to parent?

Comment: @Tison You can create a deep copy of your object using `Object.assign` function and use it in your child component.

Comment: I tried, but no result...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dvqyjr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks a lot! But i think this behavior is not correct... I thought that when I want changes to be reflected back from child to parent, I would use two-way-binding [(foo)]="foo"

Comment: @Tison Your thoughts are correct but it is the way it's working with value types only. With reference types it is different as you can see.

Answer (score 0):

From the Angular documentation at [Reactive Forms - Step 2: Associating the FormGroup model and view](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view):

> A form group tracks the status and changes for each of its controls, so if one of the controls changes, the parent control also emits a new status or value change.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one with the form:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <input formControlName="name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It all comes to [Explaining Value vs. Reference in Javascript](https://codeburst.io/explaining-value-vs-reference-in-javascript-647a975e12a0) as well as [Angular's Change Detection](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Overall, @benshabatnoam already answered you'r question - in order to execute change detection - you need to change object reference, either by old fashioned way:

```
Object.assign(this._from, this.form);
```

Or ES6 way:

```
this._from = {...this.form}
```